# Why i get extra char '^@' when writing char to a big file using byteBuffer in Java

Tags: java, file, io, character, filewriter

I am trying to write chars to a file, not sure why it writes `^@`

```
^@1^@:^@1^@ ^@2^@ ^@3^@ ^@3^@0^@4^@
```

This is expected output

```
1:1 2 3 3 0 4
```

Interestingly, for smaller file output (when it is around few hundred lines long) I don't get this weird behavior.

But, when output is in 100000+ lines then only I notice this weird behavior.

here is my code fragment

```
final static int charByteSize= 2; // 1 char =2 bytes

writeTofile(FileChannel fc, ResultClass result) throws IOException {

        int key= result.getKey();
        List<Integer> values= result.getValues();
           StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();        
        sb.append(key+":");
        for(int value:values)
        {
            sb.append(value+" "); // space delimited value list
        }

        String stringToWrite=sb.toString().trim()+"\n"; //add newline char in end
        char[] arrToWrite=stringToWrite.toCharArray();

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(arrToWrite.length*charByteSize);

        for(char theChar: arrToWrite)
        {
            buf.putChar(theChar);
        }

        buf.flip();     
        fc.write(buf);

}
```

here is calling function **pseudo-code** in case you need to see it

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
         RandomAccessFile bfc = new RandomAccessFile(theFile, "rw");
         FileChannel fc = bfc.getChannel();    

           for() // run this loop 100000+ times
           {
            ResultClass result= getResultAfterSomeComplexCalculation();  
            writeTofile(fc,result);
           }


           fc.close();
           bfc.close

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// 1 char =2 bytes
```

No it isn't! Storage wise this is true; but on every other aspect, this is wrong. A `char` is just the basic storage unit for a character in Java; more precisely, it is a UTF-16 code unit. And note that supplementary Unicode characters (U+10000 and greater) require two chars.

And what you store in files are not chars, but *bytes*. Which means you first need to encode your string to a byte array; for instance:

```
final byte[] array = theString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Then write these bytes to the output file.

Comment: +1, thanks. I learned a new thing today. Since you said 2 bytes are used to store char, so when I want to read the same file back one-char-at-a-time, I can safely read by allocating 2 bytes to byteBuffer, or that would be wrong too?

Comment: OK, what I really meant is that storage-wise a char is 16 bits and a byte is 8 bits; sorry that you got confused. In order to read back text, you can't do what you say either. You need to decode the byte stream into a char stream. For instance, by wrapping an input stream which contains your bytes into an `InputStreamReader`, not forgetting to specify the character coding (`Charset`) to use!